# Loops in Assembly: TASM on 8086 (DosBox)

Tags: memory, video, x86-16, tasm

I'm trying to loop this code which writes a character "Q" to an address in the video memory segment b800, specified by es:[di]

here I've attempted to increment the loop by two (since every screen position consists of two bytes, color and attribute), but the code only produces the the character in the first location. I think I don't understand how to use cx, because I thought that this should loop 100 times.

```
.model small
.stack
.code
main:

sub cx, cx
mov cx, 100

dates:

mov ax,0B800h          
mov es,ax               
sub di, di               
mov di, 200
add di, 2 
mov ah, 5               
mov al, 'Q'              
mov es:[di], ax 

loop dates


mov ax,4C00h           
int 21h

end main
```

Answer (score 1):

OMG, haven't been doing assembly programming for ages, but there are some obvious mistakes:

- the initial `sub cx,cx` sets cx to 0, but this is useless, as you `mov cx,100` the next line
- you set values for `es` `di` etc new for every loop cycle, so all iterations write to same location. Solution: move the dates: label before `add di,2`
- you dont have a proper loop counter, so you should replace `loop dates` with someting like

dec cx

jnz dates

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I have no experience with assembly so this is really helpful. If loops require such a counter though then what is the use of the loop instruction?

Comment: Well, well, have fun :-) Reminds me of the days when such mistakes killed the whole machine. But again, those where the times when PCs had a real reset button and MS-DOS booted faster from floppy disks than nowadays Windows from its solid state disk ;-)

Comment: i'm glad not to have been in the game at that time, but I have the utmost respect for those who were.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: you are right, "loop dates" would have been perfectly OK. Sorry for adding confusion here, just forgot that "loop" is a valid 8086 instruction...